# Trying to solve $\frac{f(x) f(y) - f(xy)}{3} = x + y + 2$ for $f(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that
> $$\frac{f(x) f(y) - f(xy)}{3} = x + y + 2$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Find $f(x)$.

I started by multiplying both sides by $3$, which gets
$$f(x)f(y)-f(xy)=3x+3y+6.$$

I tried to find something by substituting $y=0$, so
$$f(x)f(0)-f(0)=3x+6.$$

However, I don't see anything useful. How would I continue on this problem.

Comment: Related [Let $f:R \to R$ be a function with $\frac{f(x)f(y)-f(xy)}{3} = x+y+2$ for all real numbers $x,y$. List all possible values for $f(36)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965827)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting $x=y=0$ in the functional equation yields 
$$f(0)^2-f(0)-6=0 \implies f(0)=3 \text{ or } f(0)=-2$$
Set $y=0$ to obtain 
$$f(0)(f(x)-1)=3x+6$$
Now $f$ can be determined by substituting the values obtained for $f(0)$. Substituting back into the original functional equation tells us that only one of them is valid.

Finally, we have a unique solution for $f$:
$$f(x) = x+3$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f$ is a solution. Do the susbsitution $y=0$ and now suppose $f(0) = 0$. This means that for all $x$, $0 = 3x+6$. This is absurd. Thus, you can conclude that if $f$ is a solution, $f(0) \neq 0$. So you can divide by $f(0)$ and find out that $f(x) = \frac{3x+6}{f(0)} +1$. Conversely, is this a solution? Compute for what value of the constant $f(0)$ it satisfies the desired relation.